# Compiling Issue?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am currently working on a tic tac toe program for an assignment. The issue I am having is when I count my player (either the 'X' player or the 'Y' player), it seems to be counting both players as the same. For instance, after the third play, it sees three plays and counts it as a winner, even though only two plays of one player and one play of the other have been completed.

```
public class TicTacToeApp
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          TicTacToeView view = new TicTacToeView();
          TicTacToeModel model = new TicTacToeModel();
          TicTacToeViewController controller = new             
          TicTacToeViewController(view,model);
          view.setVisible(true);
    }
 }
public class TicTacToeModel 
{

    double xpos,ypos,xr,yr;
    char[][] position = {{' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' '}};


   public void computePos(int row, int col, int h, int w)
   {
      xpos=(col+0.5)*w/3.0;
      ypos=(row+0.5)*h/3.0;
      xr=w/8.0;
      yr=h/8.0;
   }

public boolean isEmpty(int xpos, int ypos)
{

  if(position[xpos][ypos]==' ')
     return true;

  return false;
}

public void placeO(int xpos, int ypos) 
{

  position[xpos][ypos]='O';

}

public int putX(){
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<3;j++) {
            if(position[i][j]==' ') {
                position[i][j]='X';
                return 0;
            }
        }
  }
    return -1; //some error occurred. This is odd. No cells were free.
}


public void printBoard(){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        System.out.println(position[i][0]+"|"+position[i][1]+"|"+position[i][2]);
}
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TicTacToeView extends JFrame{

private JButton oButton, xButton;
public JPanel board;
public ArrayList<Shape> shapes;

public TicTacToeView(){
    shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    JPanel topPanel=new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(board=new Board(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
}


private class Board extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w=getWidth();
        int h=getHeight();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Draw the grid
        g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, w, h));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, h/3, w, h/3));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, h*2/3, w, h*2/3));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(w/3, 0, w/3, h));
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(w*2/3, 0, w*2/3, h));
        //draw circles and xs by visiting elements in the array List.
        for(Shape shape : shapes){
            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }
    }
}

public void addMouseListener(MouseListener ml){

  board.addMouseListener(ml);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToeView ttv = new TicTacToeView();
    ttv.setVisible(true);

}
}

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TicTacToeViewController implements MouseListener{

TicTacToeView view;
TicTacToeModel model;
Color oColor=Color.BLUE, xColor=Color.RED;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public TicTacToeViewController(TicTacToeView view, TicTacToeModel model) { 
  this.view  = view;
  this.model = model;

  view.addMouseListener(this);
 }

public void play(int xpos, int ypos) {
  if (model.isEmpty(xpos,ypos)) {

     model.placeO(xpos, ypos);

     drawBoard();
     view.repaint();
        model.putX();
        if(didWin("X")){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"X Wins","Winner", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
           }
        if(didWin("O"))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O Wins","Winner",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  



  }
}


   public void drawBoard() {
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)view.board.getGraphics();

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) 
     for(int j=0; j<3;j++) {
        model.computePos(i,j,view.board.getHeight(),view.board.getWidth());
        double xpos = model.xpos;
        double xr = model.xr;
        double ypos = model.ypos;
        double yr = model.yr;
        if (model.position[i][j]=='O') {

           view.shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(xpos-xr, ypos-yr, xr*2, yr*2));
        }
        else if (model.position[i][j]=='X') {
           view.shapes.add(new Line2D.Double(xpos-xr, ypos-yr, xpos+xr, ypos+yr));
           view.shapes.add(new Line2D.Double(xpos-xr, ypos+yr, xpos+xr, ypos-yr));
        }
        System.out.println("Coords: xpos:"+xpos+", ypos:"+ypos+", xr"+xr+", yr"+yr);
     }
}
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  int ypos=e.getX()*3/view.getWidth();
  int xpos=e.getY()*3/view.getHeight();
  //System.out.println("Play "+xpos+","+ypos);
  play(xpos,ypos);
}

public boolean didWin(char player) {

  int count = 0;
  int count2 = 0; 

  for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
  {
     for(int j= 0; j<3; j++)
     {
        if(model.position[i][j]==player)
        {
           count++;
           if(count ==2)
              return true;
        }

     }
     count=0;
  }
     for(int k = 0; k<3; k++)
     {
        for(int l= 0; l<3; l++)
        {
           if(model.position[l][k]==player)
           {
              count2++;
              if(count2 ==2)
                 return true;
           }


        }
           count2=0;
     }
     if(model.position[0][0]==player && model.position[1][1]==player && model.position[2][2]==player)
        return true;

     if(model.position[0][2]==player && model.position[1][1]==player && model.position[2][0]==player)
        return true;


  return false;
  }

}
```

My question is if someone can look over my logic and see why the game only allows three moves. In other words, the O goes, the X goes, then the O goes, and the game announces a winner. Also, I am not looking for a code answer, but rather which part I should inspect to fix my code.

Comment: You're not asking for a "code answer" but you are asking for a debugging answer. Make sure each class and function do what you think they do independently -- not by reading them again as I'm sure you've done many times, but by testing them. You don't have to formally test them; just write a little code that uses each piece, one at a time, and make sure it behaves ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you want your count to see if it's == 3 or at least > 2, not == 2.

Comment: You, my good sir, are a genius. Thank you. I'm not sure how I let that slip by.

Comment: It's easy to confuse counting index positions (which start at and include 0) with regular counting (which starts at but does not include 0)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the error is in the didWin () method if everything else works.

Comment: That's where I'm focusing right now, too. It just seems to me like my logic should be ok...

Answer (score 4):

I think when you call the didWin I only used one ' ' don't think it really changes anything tho